# Outlook VBA code not picking up all contact records with multiple email addresses and fax numbers

Tags: vba, email, outlook, grouping, contacts

This Outlook `VBA` code loops through each contact item in the objContacts collection. It checks some custom user properties named 1st, CIC, MC, Asia, Comm, COMI, CoU, RSC, SC, SRC, and MyCategory. If a user property value is true, the code sets the strGroupName variable to the name of the user property and checks if a `distribution list`/ `Group` with that name already exists in the "Test local contacts" folder. If the distribution list does not exist, the code creates a new distribution list and sets its DLName property to the name of the user property.

The code then creates a new Recipient object using the current contact item and resolves it to get the contact's email address. Finally, the code adds the resolved recipient to the distribution list using the AddMember method and saves the distribution list.

**The macro works, both for adding and deleting members. However, it is still not picking up all the records that it should. I think the record contained more than one email address and/or a fax number, are the one that did not pick up. can any buddy ad a clue whats going wrong here? what should be the best approach to achieve the same results**

```
Sub FindTestLocalContactsFolder()

    Dim objNS  As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim personalFolders As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    
        Dim objContacts As Outlook.Items
        Dim objGroup As Outlook.DistListItem
        Dim strGroupName As String
        Dim strField As String
        Dim blnChecked As Boolean
        
        
            Dim objGroupItem As Variant
            Dim objContact As Variant
            Dim olRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    
    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Set personalFolders = objNS.Folders("Personal folders")
    
    For Each folder In personalFolders.Folders
        If folder.name = "Test local contacts" Then
            MsgBox "Found 'Test local contacts folder' with Contacts: " & folder.Items.count
            ' Do something with the folder here
            Set objContacts = folder.Items
            
            Exit For
        End If
    Next folder
    
    If objContacts Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Did not found 'Test local contacts' folder!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    For Each objContact In objContacts
    If TypeOf objContact Is Outlook.ContactItem Then
        For i = 1 To 11
            Select Case i
                Case 1
                    strField = "1st"
                Case 2
                    strField = "CIC"
                Case 3
                    strField = "MC"
                Case 4
                    strField = "Asia"
                Case 5
                    strField = "Comm"
                Case 6
                    strField = "COMI"
                Case 7
                    strField = "CoU"
                Case 8
                    strField = "RSC"
                Case 9
                    strField = "SC"
                Case 10
                    strField = "SRC"
                Case 11
                    strField = "MyCategory"
            End Select
            
            blnChecked = False
            If Not objContact.UserProperties(strField) Is Nothing Then
                If objContact.UserProperties(strField).Value = True Then
                    blnChecked = True
                End If
            End If
            
            If blnChecked = True Then
                strGroupName = strField
                Set objGroup = Nothing
                
                For Each objGroupItem In folder.Items
                    If objGroupItem.Class = olDistributionListItem Or objGroupItem.Class = 69 Then
                        If objGroupItem.DLName = strGroupName Then
                            Set objGroup = objGroupItem
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
                
                If objGroup Is Nothing Then
                    Set objGroup = folder.Items.Add(olDistributionListItem)
                    objGroup.DLName = strGroupName
                    objGroup.Save
                End If
                
                    
                Set olRecipient = Application.Session.CreateRecipient(objContact)
                    olRecipient.Resolve
                    objGroup.AddMember olRecipient
                    objGroup.Save
                
            End If
        Next i
    End If
    Next objContact
    
    
    Set objGroup = Nothing
    Set objGroupItem = Nothing
    Set objContact = Nothing
    Set objContacts = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set personalFolders = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

**"Contacts layout"**
[image: Contacts layout]

Answer (score 0):

`Namespace.CreateRecipient` takes a string. You are passing an object (`objContact`), which gets converted by VBA to a string using its default property, which is `FileAs`.

Pass the relevant address instead, e.g., `Application.Session.CreateRecipient(objContact.Email2Address)`

That being said, OOM does not allow to add contacts to a DL, you can only do that through the UI. If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it exposes [RDODistListItem](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDODistListItem.htm).`AddContact` method, which adds the contact and its specified address type (1,2, 3, business fax, etc.). Off the top of my head:

```
If objGroup Is Nothing Then
  set rSession = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  rSession.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set rFolder = rSession.GetFolderFromID(folder.EntryID)
  Set objGroup = rFolder.Items.Add(olDistributionListItem)
  objGroup.DLName = strGroupName
  objGroup.AddContact(objContact, 1) 'add Email2Address
  objGroup.Save
End If
```

Also, instead of looping through all items in a folder searching for a DL, you can use `Items.Find`:

```
set objGroup = folder.Items.Find("@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062004-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8053001F"" = '" & strGroupName  &"'")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer: syntax for the `find` with `sql` is not correct. also I cannot implement it on others computer as it requires `dll`. I am looking for a way to figure out the cause of the problem and then workaround code which I am sure VBA standalone can do.

Comment: I just change `                Set olRecipient = Application.Session.CreateRecipient(objContact.Email1Address)
` and get the first email address, it work very well. can you help me if that is all right?

Comment: The `Find` syntax is correct - I verified it by running the code before posting. Are you getting a particular error? As for passing an email address, yes, that will work, but the DL member won't be linked to the contact - if you double click on it in the DL, it will open a one-off entry, not the contact.

Comment: There was a missing quote in the SQL query - try it again.